# jQuery POST method not returning data from stored procedure with valid parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've been trying to figure out how to get some type of return response from a jQuery call but cannot.  Here's the situation:  I've written a stored procedure with 3 parameters.  One of those parameters are optional.  Here they are:

1  salesman - varchar
2  billto - int
3  accounttype - varchar

When I execute the stored procedure using the following parameters, it returns perfectly fine (stored procedure ran as an ACTMGR)

```
**EXEC  return_value = dbo.sp_widgets_salesandmargin_byOutisdeSP
        salesman = N'jordanjo',
        billto = 103876,
        accountType = N'actmgr'**
```

When I execute it again, this time as a 'JOG' in the accountType parameter, jQuery doesn't return anything...nothing...no response...no errors...nothing???  Here is the call that's "failing":

```
**EXEC  return_value = dbo.sp_widgets_salesandmargin_byOutisdeSP
        salesman = N'jordanjo',
        billto = 104611,
        accountType = N'JOG'**
```

For the purpose of simplicity, let's call the 1st execution "ran as an account manager" while the 2nd execution is called "ran as a JOG SPECIALIST".

Here's the issue though....when I execute both instances (and options as supplied above), they both return valid data when ran directly from SSMS
...
From asp.net and C#'s code environment, I've done the following:

1. Created a standard input html button to bind a javascript function that passes those parameters.
2. In the javascript function, I 'alert()' those values and they are valid.
3. In the same function, I've setup a jQuery 'post.done(function(){ code block awaiting the return to 'alert()' the results
4. A separate function was written to setup, configure and execute the ajax through the POST() method (see code)
5. Once the POST (ajax) is complete, the 1st function against has the ".don()" listener awaiting to do something with the results, which again for now is a simple alert() statement.
6. When I run all of this (asp.net, jQuery and stored procedure) from end to end it only returns an alert() output when ran as an Account Manager???

I am not seeing why only one (ACTMGR) is working while the other execution run is not (JOG)....I also need help to setup a trap on the POST method to see if indeed it is coming back with something...thank you!!

CODE: -------------------

[HTML to fire javascript event]

```
<input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="init_crm('JORDANJO', 'JOG');return false;"/>
```

[javascript event tied to HTML button]

```
function init_crm(billto, accounttype) {
                var o = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Session["USER"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() %>';
                var b = parseInt(billto);
                var a = accounttype.trim();

                reloadCRM(o,b,a);
                **post.done(function (response) {
                    alert('from outside\n\n' + response.d);
                });**
};
```

[javascript function to configure and run ajax]

```
function reloadCRM(o,b,a) {
    alert("reloadCRM: \n\n" + o + '\n' + b + '\n' + a);

    **post = $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ota.aspx/getSalesandmargin_byOutisdeSP",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               data: JSON.stringify({
                                  salesman: o,
                                  billto: b,
                                  acccode: a
               })// end ajax
    });// end post**
};
```

[c# code-behind's PageMethod]

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string getSalesandmargin_byOutisdeSP(string salesman, string billto, string acccode)
    {
        prod cn = new prod();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        // - setup cmd parameters for stored procedure injection
        cn.cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 480;
        cmd.Connection = cn.cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_widgets_salesandmargin_byOutisdeSP";
        // - Parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesman", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@salesman"].Value = salesman.Trim().ToUpper();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@billto", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@billto"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(billto.Trim());

        if (acccode != null && acccode.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@accountType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@accountType"].Value = acccode.Trim().ToUpper();
        };
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        da.Dispose();
        if (cn.cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.cn.Close();
        };
        // -------------------------------------------------------- [stringify SQLDatatable data for return] 
        string returnstring = "";
        for (int r = 0; r <= 6; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                returnstring += dt.Rows[r][c] + "@@@";
            }
            returnstring += "###";
        };
        // --------------------------------------------------------  [cleanup] 
        //da2.Dispose();
        if (cn.cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.cn.Close();
        };
        cn.cn.Dispose();
        return returnstring;
    }
```

[actual stored procedure]

Comment: It could be related to case. 'JOG' is validated as upper case in the query but all others are lower case.  You can put   console.log('message') in the code and see how it's working

Comment: post.done(function (response, error) {  console.log(error);
                    alert('from outside\n\n' + response.d);
                });

Comment: this may sound dumb, but after all these years of programming, I've never understood (nor looked up with any reasonable effort) where 'console.log' shows itself when you use that command.  Also, any varchar field in the stored_procedures will run in lower or upper case, and with or without leading and ending non-trimmed spaces due to our collation type in SQL Server

Comment: No worries. It appears in the console window of the browser. You have to press F12 on your browser while it's running. It will show a developer tool bar in the bottom. In that click "console" tab.  you can google for Developer Tool Bar. It is very helpful for developing client side applications.

Comment: it came back with zero errors and a few INFORMATIONAL items, but they are related to my 'commenting' documentation is all.

Comment: what is `alert('from outside\n\n' + response.d);` printing in the 2nd case.

Comment: I was testing out 'scope' with the post.done() function.  If I alert() inside the 1st function, would the alert() function wait since post.done() is running in async mode (implied)....just a way for me to test that the response.d was cached and usable after post() operation

Comment: As I am debugging on the NETWORK tab (IE debugger), I see that whenever JOG is ran, I get a HTTP 500 result....but when I run this report as ACTMGR (and successful) the debugger is sending back a HTTP 200 result.  does this mean anything to anyone?

Comment: HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error. It is very generic error message. You should put try catch inside the code where stored procedure is being executed. then you will see a better exception message.

Comment: put try catch in `getSalesandmargin_byOutisdeSP` it will give you much better response. I hope you can debug this C# code by putting breakpoints. It shouldn't be complex.

Comment: yup, I tried all of that, and nothing is crashing.  Here's the basic problem, when I run the stored_procedures directly in SQL Server Studio Manager and (JORDAN, 104611, and JOG), the JOG query returns into Studio Manager with 8 rows...all is good.  When I run the exact same stored procedure and same exact parameters from ADO.Net, it returns nothing....and I do not understand

Comment: Can you edit your question to show table structure and data as well.